# getting userinformation after successful redirection from withings using withings example code

Tags: php, api, oauth, withings

I have successful redirection(callback url) from withings using withings example code.

```
http://wbsapi.withings.com/cgi-bin/measure?action=getmeas&devtype=1
&oauth_consumer_key=xxxxxxxxx
&oauth_nonce=xxxxxxx
&oauth_signature=xxxxx
&oauth_signature_method=yyyy
&oauth_timestamp=yyyyy
&oauth_token=xxxxxx
&oauth_version=1.0&userid=xxx
```

I have successfully generated `auth_token` and `oauth_token_secret`.

```
Array( [oauth_token] => xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx[oauth_token_secret] => xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx).

https://oauth.withings.com/account/access_token?
oauth_consumer_key=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
&oauth_nonce=xxxx
&oauth_signature=xxxxxxx
&oauth_signature_method=yyyyy
&oauth_timestamp=yyyyyyy
&oauth_token=yyyyyy
&oauth_version=1.0
&userid=xxxx
```

I have successful redirection(callback url) from withings. But I can't get user information. I need help to get user infomation.

Following like this:

1. First name
2. Last name
3. email
4. weight
5. etc.

Comment: Did you finally succeed ?

Comment: you have got userid=xxx. using that you can simply fetch the data from database na??

Answer (score 1):

As per the Withings API docs (https://developer.withings.com/oauth2/#section/Data-API/Index-Data-API) this information isn't available. What you receive from a successful authentication from the API is:

```json
{
  "status": 0,
  "body": {
    "user": {
      "userid": 363,
      "access_token": "a075f8c14fb8df40b08ebc8508533dc332a6910a",
      "refresh_token": "f631236f02b991810feb774765b6ae8e6c6839ca",
      "expires_in": 10800,
      "scope": "user.info,user.metrics",
      "csrf_token": "PACnnxwHTaBQOzF7bQqwFUUotIuvtzSM",
      "token_type": "Bearer"
    }
  }
}
```

Unfortunately there are no other API calls to fetch more user info - you will need to ask the user to fill this in on your application.